# Updating object with core data inserts a new record

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data

I'm trying to update a record in core data but it is actually inserting a new record. The following code is suposed to unlock the next level of my game.

```
- (void)unlockNextLevel
{
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *levelEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Level"
                                                   inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:levelEntity];

    int nextLevelPosition = [self.position intValue] + 1;

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                              [NSString stringWithFormat:@"position == %i",
                               nextLevelPosition]];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    NSError *error;

    NSArray *result = [[self managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                                          error:&error];

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", error.description);
    }

    if (result.count > 0) {
        Level *nextLevel = result[0];

        nextLevel.locked = [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];

        [self saveContext];
    }
}
```

Here i fetch an object by the value of it's position, wich is supposed to be unique (by convention), and then change it's "locked" property. I'm expecting to get it updated but core data is inserting a new record...

The object I'm updating has a relation to the world it belongs. So a World has many Levels and a level only has one World.

I think it's worth mentioning that the record inserted in SQLite has no reference to a World (id of world is null).

Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following line is where the new "Level" entity is created.

```
NSEntityDescription *levelEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Level"
                                               inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
```

I think you can just initialise the fetch request using the following code instead:

```
NSFetchRequest *req = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Level"];
```

and remove the following line:

```
 [fetchRequest setEntity:levelEntity];
```

Answer (score 2):

**Update record in core data entity swift 4**

```
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Users")

    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "age = %@ AND username = %@",self.dictData[0].value(forKey: "age") as! CVarArg,self.dictData[0].value(forKey: "username") as! CVarArg)

    do {

        let result = try context.fetch(request)

        let objUpdate = result[0] as! NSManagedObject

        let strUN = txtFldUserName.text!
        let strPassword = txtFldPassword.text!
        let strAge = txtFldAge.text!

        // put all entity field
        objUpdate.setValue(strUN, forKey: "username")
        objUpdate.setValue(strPassword, forKey: "password")
        objUpdate.setValue(strAge, forKey: "age")

        print("update success!")
        try context.save()

    } catch {
        print("Failed")
    }
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this way. First fetch the required entity with some unique attribute value like articleID. If you get the entity as nil then create new entity instance or else update it.

```
Entity * entityInstance = nil;
 entityInstance = [self fetchEntityForID:entityInstanceID inContext:context];

 if (entityInstance == nil) 
{
 entityInstance = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Entity" inManagedObjectContext:context];
}

-(Entity *)fetchEntityForID:(NSNumber *) articleID inContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *) writeContext
{
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Entity"];
    NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"articleID == %@",articleID];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    NSArray *fetchedArray = [writeContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
    if ([fetchedArray count] > 0) {
        return [fetchedArray objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Hope it helps :)